# How to print all key value pairs in Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

My apologies for the potentially stupid question, I'm an absolute beginner to Ruby and code in general.

I have set up a hash with some predetermined values. I want to ask the user for input, if that input matches an existing key, I want the corresponding value to be updated (+ 1, in this case). Then I want to print all the current up-to-date values.

```
hash = {"apple": 6, "banana": 2, "carrot": 3}

order = gets.chomp.downcase

hash.each do |key, value|
    if key.to_s == order
       value += 1
       puts "Your order includes: #{value} #{key}."   
    end
end
```

My problem is that I only know how to print a single key value pair.

E.g. if the user inputs "apple", I'd like the output to say "Your order includes: 7 apple, 2 banana, 3 carrot."

Comment: I think, You would like to pluralise 'apple' to 'apples' when count is greater than 1.

Comment: Remember you can look up things in a hash, you don't need to spin over it and compare. `if (value = hash[order])` does all this in one shot. The approach you have here gets incrementally slower as the number of items increases. The lookup method takes about the same amount of time regardless of the number of entries.

Comment: The crux of the issue here, is that `value += 1` doesn't update the hash. You need to use [`Hash#[]=`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
hash = {apple: 6, banana: 2, carrot: 3}
order = gets.chomp.downcase.to_sym
hash[order] = hash.fetch(order, 0) + 1
puts "Your order includes: " + hash.map { |k, v| "#{v} #{k}" }.join(", ")
```

Some notes:

- your hash initialization `hash = {"apple": 6, "banana": 2, "carrot": 3}`. the keys of your hash seem strings, but if you use that syntax with the colon, they become symbols. So, you have two choice. this syntax:

  ```
  hash = {"apple" => 6, "banana" => 2, "carrot" => 3}
  ```

  or you can use symbols as I did and convert the user input in a symbol
- what's really cool about hash is that you don't need to iterate through the elements to find what you're looking for. There's a mapping between keys and values, so it's easy find and update a value
- in the third row, I'm dealing with the fact that the key could not be in the hash, I used `fetch` to have 0 in that case. then, I increment and I assign back to that key

Answer (score 1):

The question does not specify if you want to mutate the initial hash, so I suppose you do. Then the following will do.

```
hash = Hash.new(0).merge(apple: 6, banana: 2, carrot: 3)
hash[gets.chomp.downcase.to_sym] += 1

puts "Your order includes: " <<
  hash.map { |k, v| [v, k].join(' ') }.join(', ')
```

or:

```
puts hash.reduce("Your order includes: ") { |acc, (k, v)|
  acc << "#{v} #{k}, "
}[0..-3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to initialize the hash providing a default value ([Hash#default](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-i-default))

```
basket = {'apple' => 6, 'banana' => 2, 'carrot' => 3}
basket.default = 0 # <-- set default 0 for start counting new keys
```

Define a method to present the data:

```
def show(basket)
  puts "Your order includes:"
  basket.each{ |key, value| puts "#{value}: #{key}" } 
end
```

Capture user input in a loop (explanation in comments):

```
loop do
  puts "Place your order:"
  order = gets.downcase.chomp # <-- format the input
  break if order == '0' # <-- breaks the input loop if this contition is matched
  next unless basket.has_key? order # <-- skip to next loop no matches with hash keys or remove this line if you want to count also non initialised keys
  basket[order] += 1 # <-- increment by one the key
  show(basket) # <-- call the metod to show the basket
end

show(basket)
```